# Print a 256-color test pattern in the terminal

Tags: command-line, colors

How do I print a 256-colour test pattern in my terminal?

I want to check that my terminal correctly supports 256 colours.

Comment: type `/cubes` in irssi ([source](https://github.com/irssi/irssi/pull/48))

Answer (score 158, accepted):

### 256-colour test pattern

To get the below image, use:

```
curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/HaleTom/89ffe32783f89f403bba96bd7bcd1263/raw/e50a28ec54188d2413518788de6c6367ffcea4f7/print256colours.sh | bash
```

[image: 256-colour test pattern]

The [gist `bash`/`zsh` code](https://gist.github.com/HaleTom/89ffe32783f89f403bba96bd7bcd1263) is [`shellcheck`](https://shellcheck.net) clean, and also supports "Look Ma, no subprocesses!".

---

Alternatively, for a `bash` quicky:

```
for i in {0..255} ; do
    printf "\x1b[48;5;%sm%3d\e[0m " "$i" "$i"
    if (( i == 15 )) || (( i > 15 )) && (( (i-15) % 6 == 0 )); then
        printf "\n";
    fi
done
```

For total overkill, the granddaddy of the lot is `terminal-colors`, a [572-line script](https://github.com/eikenb/terminal-colors/blob/master/terminal-colors) with multiple [output formats](https://github.com/eikenb/terminal-colors).

You can also [print a true color (24-bit) test pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404415/143394).

Comment: I like your comment on the grayscale on the scripts GitHub page - "#Not 50, but 24 Shades of Grey"

Comment: Here's another 24-bit color test: https://gist.github.com/lifepillar/09a44b8cf0f9397465614e622979107f

Comment: To run `terminal-colors`, do `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eikenb/terminal-colors/master/terminal-colors | python`

Comment: @masterxilo what is `terminal-colors` and how does it compare to the options I suggested?

Comment: what would the printf pattern look like for coloring the text instead of the background?

Answer (score 43):

I found a [nice Python script for that on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/justinabrahms/1047767) written by Justin Abrahms which also prints the hex codes of the colours.

Download the script to current working directory

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/justinabrahms/1047767/raw/a79218b6ca8c1c04856968d2d202510a4f7ec215/colortest.py
```

give it execute permission

```
chmod +x colortest.py
```

Run it:

```
./colortest.py
```

[image]

Here's the script in full in case of link-rot:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Ported to Python from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1349

print "Color indexes should be drawn in bold text of the same color."
print

colored = [0] + [0x5f + 40 * n for n in range(0, 5)]
colored_palette = [
    "%02x/%02x/%02x" % (r, g, b) 
    for r in colored
    for g in colored
    for b in colored
]

grayscale = [0x08 + 10 * n for n in range(0, 24)]
grayscale_palette = [
    "%02x/%02x/%02x" % (a, a, a)
    for a in grayscale 
]

normal = "\033[38;5;%sm" 
bold = "\033[1;38;5;%sm"
reset = "\033[0m"

for (i, color) in enumerate(colored_palette + grayscale_palette, 16):
    index = (bold + "%4s" + reset) % (i, str(i) + ':')
    hex   = (normal + "%s" + reset) % (i, color)
    newline = '\n' if i % 6 == 3 else ''
    print index, hex, newline,
```

Comment: Or: `curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/justinabrahms/1047767/raw/a79218b6ca8c1c04856968d2d202510a4f7ec215/colortest.py | python`

Answer (score 16):

While not *quite* a "test pattern", I have [xterm-color-chooser](https://nullroute.eu.org/redir/xterm-color-chooser):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grawity/code/master/term/xterm-color-chooser | python3`

Comment: new URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grawity/code/main/misc/xterm-color-chooser

Answer (score 10):

Yet another script, written by me, is located in the VTE repository: https://git.gnome.org/browse/vte/plain/perf/256test.sh?h=vte-0-38.

It requires a window of 120-ish or more columns, but arranges the colors of the 6x6x6 cube nicely and compactly. The first digits of the indices are stripped for compactness, you can easily figure them out. The vertical bars provide you the ability to examine the exact RGB of the foreground color without antialiasing kicking in (as it does at the digits).

The top of the output (not shown in the screenshot below) demonstrates the craziness that goes around with the bold vs. bright ambiguity, namely that the boldness escape sequence combined with one of the legacy 8 colors' escape sequence for the foreground also switches to the bright counterpart color, whereas with the new style (256-color capable) escape sequences this is no longer the case, not even for the first 8 colors. At least that's how xterm and VTE (GNOME Terminal etc.) behave.

This screenshot shows about half of the output:

[image: Output of 256test.sh in GNOME Terminal]

Comment: `curl -s -L https://git.gnome.org/browse/vte/plain/perf/256test.sh?h=vte-0-38 | bash`

Answer (score 10):

A one-liner

background color

```
for i in {0..255}; do printf '\e[48;5;%dm%3d ' $i $i; (((i+3) % 18)) || printf '\e[0m\n'; done
```

foreground color

```
for i in {0..255}; do printf '\e[38;5;%dm%3d ' $i $i; (((i+3) % 18)) || printf '\e[0m\n'; done
```

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps superfluous but I've written a version that prints the 256 colors using the background with automatic shell width detection so the colors are more easily visible.

https://gist.github.com/WoLpH/8b6f697ecc06318004728b8c0127d9b3

[image: 256 color test demo]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import shutil
import subprocess


def get_width(default=80):
    '''Attempt to detect console width and default to 80'''
    try:
        columns, rows = shutil.get_terminal_size()
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            _, columns = subprocess.check_output(['stty', 'size']).split()
        except OSError:
            columns = os.environ.get('COLUMNS', default)

    columns = int(columns) - 77
    # Since we have 6 columns with 1 space on each side, we can increment the
    # size for every 12 extra columns
    return max(0, columns / 12)


# Loosely based on https://gist.github.com/justinabrahms/1047767
colored = [0] + list(range(95, 256, 40))
colored_palette = [
    (r, g, b)
    for r in colored
    for g in colored
    for b in colored
]


grayscale_palette = [(g, g, g) for g in range(8, 240, 10)]


esc = '\033['
# Reset all colors sequence
reset = esc + '0m'
# Regular color
normal = esc + '38;5;{i}m'
# Bold color
bold = esc + '1;' + normal
# Background color
background = esc + '48;5;{i}m'

pattern = (
    '{normal}{background}{padding:^{width}}{i:^3d} '  # pad the background
    '{r:02X}/{g:02X}/{b:02X}'  # show the hex rgb code
    '{padding:^{width}}'  # pad the background on the other side
    '{reset}'  # reset again
)

base_context = dict(reset=reset, padding='', width=get_width())

for i, (r, g, b) in enumerate(colored_palette + grayscale_palette, 16):
    context = dict(i=i, r=r, g=g, b=b, color=r + g + b, **base_context)
    context.update(bold=bold.format(**context))
    context.update(background=background.format(**context))

    # Change text color from black to white when it might become unreadable
    if max(r, g, b) > 0xCC:
        context.update(normal=normal.format(i=0))
    else:
        context.update(normal=normal.format(i=255))

    print(pattern.format(**context), end='')

    # Print newlines when needed
    if i % 6 == 3:
        print()
    else:
        print(' ', end='')
```

Comment: If anyone wants to run this script in a one liner, run `curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/WoLpH/8b6f697ecc06318004728b8c0127d9b3/raw/250eb2e3f2acca1c51aa52adf611ec0380291e8a/colortest.py | python3`

Comment: I suggest `curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/WoLpH/8b6f697ecc06318004728b8c0127d9b3/raw/colortest.py | python3`

Answer (score 3):

I liked @Tom's answer, but depending on the use case I like to be able to see black and white on the color, and the color on white and black. So I modified it a bit to:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..255} ; do
    # Black FG on color BG
    printf "\e[30;48;5;%sm%4d " "$i" "$i"

    # White FG on color BG
    printf "\e[97m%4d " "$i"

    # Color FG on black BG
    printf "\e[40;38;5;%sm%4d " "$i" "$i"

    # Color FG on white BG
    printf "\e[107m%4d " "$i"

    # Check whether to print new line
    [ $(( ($i +  1) % 4 )) == 0 ] && set1=1 || set1=0
    [ $(( ($i - 15) % 6 )) == 0 ] && set2=1 || set2=0
    if ( (( set1 == 1 )) && (( i <= 15 )) ) || ( (( set2 == 1 )) && (( i > 15 )) ); then
        printf "\e[0m\n";
    fi
done
```

Which prints something like this (first few colors shown):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but here's a Python 3 / bash one-liner:

```
python -c "print('\t'.join(f'\u001b[1;38;5;{s}m{s.ljust(4)}' + ('\n' if not int(s) % 8 else '') for s in (str(i) for i in range(256))) + '\u001b[0m')"
```